# Select department/s name/s with the highest number of highest grades

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having 3 tables - student, department and exam_results. What I am trying to do here is to select all of the department/s name/s which have the highest grade for example 6.

I have tried the following query but in this example's case where we have 2 departments with grade 6 but the Informatics one has 2 max grades and Chemistry has only 1 I am still retrieving the Chemistry department name which should not be returned but only the Chemistry department name(also if we have 2 max grades for Chemistry we should be able to retrieve both Informatics and Chemistry records).

```
SELECT department
FROM (SELECT d.department_name as department, count(e_r.grade) as cnt
      FROM exam_results e_r
      INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
      INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
      WHERE e_r.grade = 6
      GROUP BY d.department_name
     ) as ex;
```

Also with the following query I was able to accomplish to retrieve the department/s name/s and the count of the given 'n' grade in the WHERE clause but for some reason I am not able to accomplish what I really want.

```
SELECT department_name, max(cnt) as cnt
FROM (SELECT d.department_name as department_name, e_r.grade, count(e_r.grade) as cnt
      FROM exam_results e_r
      INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
      INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
      WHERE grade = 6
      GROUP BY d.department_name, e_r.grade
     ) AS ex
GROUP BY department_name;
```

Providing a dbfiddle link with the explained example: https://dbfiddle.uk/siEjfNXP

Would be glad to receive any suggestions or hints on how to achieve this, thank you!

Here are the tables with example values(all included in dbfiddle link):

Student table:

| student_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 |

Department table:

| department_id | department_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Informatics |
| 2 | Biology |
| 3 | Physics |
| 4 | Geography |
| 5 | Chemistry |

Exam_results table:

| student_id | grade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 6 |
| 10 | 5 |

Comment: You have already provided an answer. Can you make the question of this post explicit?

Comment: It is not an answer because with the provided example I should not retrieve the Chemistry department name but only the Informatics one as Informatics has 2 max grades of 6 which is greater than 1 max grade of 6 for Chemistry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you want only one row (the department with most biggest grade), you can order by your count of grades descendently, then limit rows to 1.

```
SELECT d.department_name as department
FROM exam_results e_r
INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE e_r.grade = 6
GROUP BY d.department_name
ORDER BY COUNT(e_r.grade) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HxNu5gzC).

---

If you're allowing more than one max value, you can use the `DENSE_RANK` window function to assign a ranking order to your counts, then get all the records that have denserank = 1.

```
SELECT department
FROM (SELECT d.department_name as department,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(e_r.grade) DESC) AS rn
      FROM exam_results e_r
      INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
      INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
      WHERE e_r.grade = 6
      GROUP BY d.department_name
     ) AS ex
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ollzu9w6).

Comment: It should not be only 1 row. Depends on the case if we have 2 departments with same maximum grade it should return 2 rows for example.

Comment: Thank you! This is working as expected. I guess the thing I missed is to use the ``DENSE_RANK`` function.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a mire flexible solitution if the ighest ranks are not 6

```
WITH CTE as
  (SELECT 
  d.department_name as department_name,e_r.grade, count(e_r.grade) as cnt
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e_r.grade DESC ,count(e_r.grade) DESC) rk
FROM  exam_results e_r
      INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
      INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
  WHERE (d.department_name,e_r.grade) IN
(select d.department_name as department_name, MAX(e_r.grade) 
      from exam_results e_r
      INNER JOIN students s ON e_r.student_id = s.student_id
      INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.department_id     
      group by d.department_name)
group by d.department_name, e_r.grade)
SELECT department_name,grade,cnt FROM CTE WHERE rk = 1
```

| department_name | grade | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Informatics | 6 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bI9OmKmM)

Comment: You can actually avoid the `WHERE () IN (<subquery>)` using a window function and an aggregation >> https://dbfiddle.uk/5nlI7w5h

Comment: It is still returning Chemistry for example even if the maximum grade 6 count is 1. 
It should only return Informatics in this case.

Comment: Yes, but along with highest grade being 6. So in this example we have Informatics that has 2 grades of 6 and Chemistry which has 1 grade of 6. So in this case we should receive only Informatics and not both.

Comment: yes i undestood and changed the answer, with a simpole adding of the order by